# How to concatenate and upload audio using Amazon S3 storage

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My goal is to retrieve two separate audio files currently stored in an `s3` bucket using the `getObject()` method and then concatenate both files and upload a combined audio clip of both `audio1` and `audio2` back to `s3` using `s3.upload()`. Is there a way to combine `audio1` and `audio2` and then upload these results back to the `s3` bucket?

```
  const audio1 = await s3.getObject({
    Bucket: 'Bucket',
    Key: bucket1.audio1.s3Key,
  }).promise();

  // the second audio file to be concatenated to the first one
  const audio2 = await s3.getObject({
    Bucket: 'Bucket',
    Key: bucket1.audio2.s3Key,
  }).promise();

  // combine and upload 'audio1' and 'audio2' as a new obj back to s3 bucket
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ffmpeg. On the command line you could do this:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:audio1.mp3|audio2.mp3" -acodec copy out.mp3
```

This combines `audio1.mp3` and `audio2.mp3` into `out.mp3`.

To do that with NodeJS you can try to use the package [fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg). Or another NodeJS wrapper for ffmpeg.